# Using tickets from Vienna to Budapest

Tags: trains, austria, hungary

I have bought a return ticket from Vienna Airport to Budapest and I need to change trains at Wien Hauptbahnhof to take the onward train to Budapest. The train to Wien Hauptbahnhof leaves the airport at 1503 hrs and arrives at Wien Hauptbahnhof at 1518 hrs. My train to Budapest is at 1542 hrs. I received an update from OBB mentioning there are some works going on and connections cannot be guaranteed.

I was wondering if I can take an earlier train to Wien Hauptbahnhof from the airport on the same ticker or do I need another ticket. I tried to go through the T&Cs but couldn't find anything in English, all in German it seems.

Has anybody tried this or do I need to buy a new ticket ?

NB:- I have a reservation on both legs of the journey and a specific train number is mentioned on the ticket too.

Comment: The answer below is mostly, but not always, true ("Sparschiene"). And the reservation is most likely gone if you take another train. ... If you can, a scan/photo of your tickets would be great.

Comment: If it's Sparschiene (which most likely it is given the information so far), you have to take the specific trains listed on your ticket. Since obviously it's not your fault that the connection most likely will be missed, I'd assume that you can take an earlier train from VIE to Wien Hbf without doing anything extra. Of course, you won't have any reservation for this train, but given that it only takes 20 minutes and is almost empty normally, this won't be a problem (ÖBB most likely won't give you the money for the reservation back because it's such a small amount).

Comment: Note that if you take the train to Hbf listed on your ticket and really miss your connection, quite likely you will be entitled to compensation (unless they informed you about the delay before/when buying the ticket). Hence they should be happy about you taking an earlier train.

Comment: @martin.koeberl It doesn't work like that ... "not my fault" doesn't translate to "I can do what I want". While there's a chance the conductor is nice enough to let it pass, taking an earlier train because of some possible delay is not ok. ... About the compensation, he was informed.

Comment: @deviantfan I'm aware of that, that's why I didn't post it as an answer and why I used "I assume" in my comment. About the compensation: "received an update" sounds to me like the information of the delay came _after_ the purchase of the ticket, in which case they are still entitled to a compensation (unless they are offered an alternative connection ...). In any case, most likely there won't be a conductor in the first train checking tickets between the airport and Hbf.

Answer (score 6):

You can use your ticket for any train that goes from Vienna Airport to Hauptbahnhof, they are valid without time limitation (Of course, one ticket can only be used in one direction). 
Just make sure to take a train that stops at Hauptbahnhof. (All the stations where a train stops are listed in the big monitors that show the time tables for all trains).

There's a regional train that departs at 14:03 and arrives at Hauptbahnhof at 14:18, if you can catch it. (RJ 864, goes to Linz but stops at Hpf).

Or later on you could get S7 at 14:18 that goes to Laa/Thaya and stop at Wien Rennweg. There change to take S1 direction Meidling, ang get out at Hauptbahnhof.

@DumbCoder please check your ticket, if it is specifically stated that you need to take the train at 15.03 then no, you cannot take any other train. You need to use that ticket with that train.

I thought of this now re-reading your question.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes it is mentioned a specific train from the airport, and has a reserved seat too, hence my query. In hindsight I should have mentioned in the query. I will update it anyway.